# Managing WCF Duplex Callback connections for Silverlight frontend

Tags: wcf, duplex

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, but here's my current "setup".

I have a silverlight client that uses Caliburn.Micro and a MEF container with a "LoadCatalog" class, to keep everything loosely coupled in an MVVM way.

I have a "common" dll where all the interfaces are kept.

All my views and viewmodels are separate projects, that only have a reference to the common dll.

The viewmodels use WCF (regular) to communicate to the backend. The frontend itself has a duplex connection to the backend.

Now here's where the question comes to mind. Whenever the backend thinks it's time to have a new screen appear at the frontend, it uses the callback channel to tell the frontend to load the next screen.

Does this seem like a good pattern to use? Or should I leave the management of what screen to load when to the frontend? I think it's nice to have this in the backend, but perhaps this is some kind of anti-pattern I'm not aware of, hence the question.

Now for argument sake, lets say I want to keep this in the backend.

What would be the best way to go about managing the collection of callback channels on the backend? If I enable SessionMode.Required on all the regular WCF endpoints, as well as the duplex channel, does this persist state together over multiple endpoints (regular+duplex)? Or will this persist state only within a single endpoint?
My guess (from the tests I have been able to do so far) is that I need to add some logic, like for example provide the frontend with a guid as soon as the callback connection is made. And then use that guid in the regular endpoint connections so the backend knows which "client" it is.

And would I "ever" be able to reliably collect all the channels and detect current state if I made a collection of the callback channels that I receive? I can intercept the callback channel now (just 1 instance atm, no collections made or anything, so single user) and use that to tell the frontend what to do. But sometimes when the client stops abrubtly (in other words when an error occurs) and I start the client again, it seems like the previous (faulted?) connection is still "re-used" or something, without luck so the communication flow stops after connection the duplex endpoint.

Does this make any sense?

Hope there's someone who has some experience in the matter that can shed some light on it for me. I'm no total newbie, but with regards to multiple connection and keeping them separated, I might need some pointers in the right direction.

Thanks!

Huron.

Comment: I managed to get this up and running. Here's what I did :

Comment: I managed to get this up and running. When I create the duplex connection from the frontend to the backend I return a unique Guid. From now on I use this guild for all communication I do with the backend. This makes the backend "recognize" the client.

In the backend I have a list of connections (grabbed the callback channel and stored it together with the Guid).

Just had to make sure to lock the list object whenever I iterate it or when I add/remove items from it, since it will be used from multiple threads by design.

The pattern to take control from the backend seems to work great so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this up and running.

When I create the duplex connection from the frontend to the backend I return a unique Guid. From now on I use this guid for all communication I do with the backend.

This makes the backend "recognize" the client.

In the backend I have a list of connections (grabbed the callback channel and stored it together with the Guid).

Just had to make sure to lock the list object whenever I iterate it or when I add/remove items from it, since it will be used from multiple threads by design.

The pattern to take control from the backend seems to work great so far.